# Script of Website Thumbnails Creation Like Google Instant Preview

Tags: thumbnails, google-instant-previews

Is there any script that is working like the Google Instant Preview ?? That gives the Small Preview of the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few if you search for "[site thumbnail](http://www.google.com/search?q=site+thumbnail)" on google.
Here is a sample of the results:

- [www.thumbalizr.com](http://www.thumbalizr.com/)
- [websnapr.com](http://www.websnapr.com/)
- [snapcasa.com](http://snapcasa.com/)
- [thumbshots.com](http://www.thumbshots.com/)

I don't have specific recommendations, but they all seem decent and some free packages.
Some others I found by checking for Similar sites:

- [www.picoshot.com](http://www.picoshot.com/)
- [thumboo.com](http://www.thumboo.com/)